# How do you populate an option value using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to populate a form option value if it's attribute **`quantity`** equals zero.
My goal is to add the a message to the current option value

My html is:

```
<select class="valid">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Select Bar</option>
    <option value="1" quantity="99">value 1 </option>
    <option value="2" quantity="0">value 2  </option>
</select>
```

So far I've tried the following in jQuery but it's not working:

```
if($(this).attr('quantity') == '0') {
    $(this).append('<span>message</span>');
}
```

Comment: You can't render html inside of an `<option>` tag

Comment: Is your goal to change `<option value="2" quantity="0">value 2  </option>` to `<option value="2" quantity="0"><span>message</span></option>`?

Comment: So if you want to change value 2 into message, update the innerHTML of the option instead of appending a html node to it.

Comment: In your example, the 'this' variable does not seem to reference your select control. (Unless something is missing here) You first need to use a selector to get to your select control, then you will be able to query one of its attribute.

Comment: @Shilly You can't render html inside of an `<option>` tag. Setting the innerHTML will have the same issue

Comment: How about something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ncx53s27/

Comment: @mrhodges You update it with a string, not a html node. Maybe I shouldve stated textContent to be more clear. `option.innerHTML = 'message'` or `option.textContent = 'message'` not sure what the JQuery equivalent is without looking it up.

Comment: Also, @Mariton, can you please define what "not working" means? Does it never hit the body of the `if` statement? does it give you a bad value? does it do nothing? what is the specific issue you are seeing?

Comment: @Shilly Based on pure inference, I think the OP wants to keep the value and add maybe a warning message like (Out of Stock) or something to that effect. Overwriting the textContent would be counter-productive I think. Now, concatinating it might make sense, but then it would make it hard to remove it if the quantity gets updated and the warning is to be removed. Hence why the OP probably wanted a span, so they could target the span to remove it. Again, that is pure inference, but I think it would make sense

Comment: @mhodges, the question is not clear enough, we can't know.

Comment: If there has to be html inside the option, it's probably better to 'fake' a select using a list so the OP can insert HTML into it. And changing the inner html or the text content won't update the value attribute on the option element. Anyways, I'd just render the message outside the select.

Comment: @Shilly `$(element).text("value")` and `$(element).html("value")` are the setters in jQuery, just for reference

Comment: Thanks. Who needs jquery anyway. ;)

Comment: @j08691 Yes that is what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: @Shilly I can try .innerhtml but  don't want to overwrite the current message, just add to it.

Comment: @Rodrigo I updated my question. Hopes it adds a bit more clarity

Comment: @Mariton I updated my answer, see if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @Rodrigo Thank You. Definitely looks helpful. I will try it out

Comment: Thanks so much for all of your comments They definitely helped me  look at my issue at different angles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can populate the `option` with like this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.valid').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).attr('quantity') == 0) {
       $(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).find('span').remove();
       $(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).append('<span>Message</span>')
    }
  });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://fiddle.jshell.net/zc32of7w/1/)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about preserving the original message, than you can simply say `$(this).text("message")`. Leave out the `<span>` since it cannot be rendered inside of an `<option>` element anyway.

```
if($(this).attr('quantity') == '0') {
    $(this).text('message');
}
```

If you want to preserve the original message, you have a couple options. One would simply be to append the new message to the original, however, it may get tricky to remove it later, so I would suggest having some sort of delimiter so you can easily identify the original vs the appended message, like so:

```
var $option = $(this);
if($option.attr('quantity') == '0') {
    $option.text($option.text().trim() + ' (message)');
}
```

Then, to remove the message, you can do something like this:

```
$option.text($option.text().slice(0, $option.text().indexOf('(')).trim());
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to not overwrite the original message?

Comment: Something like `$(this).text( $(this).text() + ' message' );`

Comment: @Mariton Updated to handle appending/removing as requested.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of what you're trying to achieve from your question, but you cannot add html elements to an option element. You can however change the text as follows:

```
$(document).on('change', '.valid', function(){
    var selected = $('.valid > option:selected');
    if(selected.attr('quantity') == '0'){
        selected.text('something else');
    } 
});
```

if you wanted to append an error you could do so by using jQuery append() or concatenating with the original value. Alternatively if you wanted it as validation outside of the select box, you could simply assign to the value of a div by replacing the line inside of the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="valid" onchange="quality(this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('quantity'));">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Select Bar</option>
    <option value="1" quantity="99">value 1 </option>
    <option value="2" quantity="0">value 2  </option>
</select>
<span id="msg"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
function quality(val) {
    if(parseInt(val) == 0){
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Message";
    }
}
```